# Creating a place type filter for the Place Autocomplete API for Android

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-places-api

This API seems to be fairly new so there aren't many questions about it here, nor many tutorials.

I followed Google's tutorial and got the Autocomplete Android api working in my app. I'm now trying to use the **AutocompleteFilter** to restrict my results to a certain region or certain types of places.

There seems to be little to no documentation for a beginner like me explaining what to do.

The AutocompleteFilter requires a Collection object. How do I change the the following values into integers?

https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table3

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is it related to android AutoCompleteTextView or Google places AutoComplete api?

If you want simpler AutoCompleteTextView, you can use library https://github.com/mobisystech/autocompletetextview.. It have AutoComplete Google places as a sample which may be helpful to you..

Comment: The question was quite clear. Read the last line before the URL. I wanted to create a Place Type filter for a Google Place Autocomplete query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem was solved by a Google employee himself whom I contacted via our Maps for Work support portal.

Here's a list of Place Types with their integer counterparts.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place

These can be used to filter the Android Place Autocomplete API.

Comment: sorry for the negative vote, it was accidental. I cannot revert it without first editing your answer. :(

Comment: @AngelosVeglektsis i upvoted that behalf of you. This is the exactly the link i am looking for thanks Asim for sharing the answer

Answer (score 6):

I cannot comment yet so I add it here a warning for the answer above:

Not all constant from Place are available for filtering with AutocompleteFilter, only two are available on Android: `Place.TYPE_GEOCODE` and `Place.TYPE_ESTABLISHMENT` ('address' appear in documentation but not as constant in `Place`)

If any other constant (e.g. `Place.TYPE_LOCALITY`) are used the request will result in this confusing status error:

```
Status{statusCode=NETWORK_ERROR, resolution=null}
```

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your requirement, an `AutocompleteFilter` can be built. This filter can then be applied to the `IntentBuilder` by using `setFilter()`.

For example:

1. If you want to restrict the results to a particular country, you could do that by:

   ```
   AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder().setCountry("IN").build();

   Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN).setFilter(typeFilter).build(this);
   ```
2. If you want to restrict the results to a particular place type, you could do that in a similar way by changing the Filter as:

   ```
   AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder().setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_REGIONS).build();
   ```

Comment: No method available as setCountry(String) in AutomCompleteFilter class.

Comment: There is an option available. You have to use the builder pattern. You can refer the documentation here: 
[link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter.Builder)

Comment: Thanks Karan. But i am not able to use setCountry() method as you mentioned in your answer. It says no such method. And i could not find any sample usage of this method anywhere. Could you help me on this.

Comment: @gReEnHoRn Sure. Can you write the code where you're facing the problem.

Comment: Thanks karan. my issue has been solved. I was using google play service version 9.0.2 where this method is not supported. Updtated my play service version and i could use your suggested method call. And its working fine and results me with coutry restricted results. And I just want to restrict language to english. Because i get regional language data for some of  searched results. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not currently possible for Android Places API. I think something like this can be achieved by Places Details API. You can check the following link: [link](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details)

Answer (score 4):

Android Place Autocomplete does not support all the types enumerated by the [link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place) provided in the previous answer.

Since v8.4 release, the supported types are provided by AutocompleteFilter as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#get_place_predictions_programmatically)

```
// AutocompleteFilter
public static final int TYPE_FILTER_NONE = 0;
public static final int TYPE_FILTER_GEOCODE = 1007;
public static final int TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS = 2;
public static final int TYPE_FILTER_ESTABLISHMENT = 34;
public static final int TYPE_FILTER_REGIONS = 4;
public static final int TYPE_FILTER_CITIES = 5;
```