# Country restriction in autocompleteFilter in android

Tags: android, filter, autocomplete, country

I am working on google places api. I use AutoComplteFilter to set the filter in search results. As menthioned in this [lynk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30725084/creating-a-place-type-filter-for-the-place-autocomplete-api-for-android/39743596?noredirect=1#comment70136469_39743596)

i try to restrict my results within the specified country. But i am not able to access this method setCountry(String country) in AutoCompleteFilter.Builder api. Am i missing something? How to use this method? FYI, i am using google playservice version 9.0.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=AIzaS...............&components=country:IS&language=en
```

Here i set country `IS -iceland` and language `english`

alternaview and [playservice above 9.6 Use this](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete)

and set `AutocompleteFilter`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. it saved my time. Updated my playservice to the latest version and i could set the country restriction. And i am using Autocomplete filter with widget. Is there a way to specify language?